# ¿Cómo se dice regionalmente "coquetear"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, españa, argentina, venezuela

### Español

(Pregunta: ¿cómo se dice "to flirt" regionalmente?)

Sé que la forma correcta de decirlo es "coquetear". Sin embargo, en México usamos la palabra "ligar". He oído que en Chile usan la palabra "jotear". Estoy buscando un verbo corto. Por ejemplo, "ligar" en vez de "echar los perros". ¿Qué palabra se usa en los siguientes países?

- España
- Argentina
- Venezuela

---

### Inglés

How do you say "to flirt"?

I know that the correct way to say it is "coquetear". However in Mexico we use the word "ligar". I've heard that in Chile they use the word "jotear". I'm looking for a short verb. For example "ligar" instead of "echar los perros". What is the word they use in the following countries?

- Spain
- Argentina
- Venezuela

Comment: En Peru se dice: "gilear"

Comment: *Coquetear* no es un sinónimo de ligar, pienso.  Coquetear es lo que se hace para atraer la atención de quien te quieres *ligar*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Argentina

- Chamullar
- Levantar

### Chile

- Jotear
- Pinchar (es anticuado)
- Tirar los cortes

### Ecuador

- Buitrear

### España

- Ligar
- Tontear

Some sentences used instead of *ligar*, just in case you find them useful:

- Echar/tirar los trastos
- Echar/tirar los tejos
- Meter/tirar fichas (algunas zonas de España)
- Pelar la pava

### Perú

- Gilear

### Uruguay

- Cargar
- Ligar
- Levantar

### Venezuela

- Pelotear

Comment: Nunca he oído "meter fichas" en España.

Comment: @CesarGon creo que solo lo usamos por el norte, al menos en el País Vasco, tienes razón.

Comment: @CesarGon en el centro de España también es muy común.

Comment: @CesarGon En Valencia se utiliza meter fichas también. La que no he oído nunca es pelar la pava. Otras alternativas usadas son "tirar la caña" o incluso "flirtear".

Comment: *Pelar la pava* me parece un poco anticuado, aunque tal vez en lugares de Andalucía siga vigente. *Meter fichas* o *echar fichas* creo que está bastante extendido geográficamente en España.

Comment: Añadiría Picar piedra, aunque sólo lo he oído en la zona norte

Comment: Como dice Albertus en su respuesta, _ligar_ no es sinónimo de _coquetear_ en España (ni en la RAE). Te vas a ligar cuando buscas entablar una relación (pasajera). Coqueteas con quien quieres ligar, para ligar.

Comment: _Pelar la pava_ según el DRAE es : "1. loc. verb. coloq. Conversar los enamorados; el hombre desde la calle, y la mujer, asomada a una reja o balcón." Supone que ya han coqueteado y están ligados

Comment: En México se podría decir *echarle los perros* a alguien. Y a veces sucede que eso pasa por medio de un *albur*, aunque se considera de mal gusto en general. O se puede decir que alguien anda *enamorando* o *cazando* a alguien.

Answer (score 12):

En España, “flirtear” y "coquetear" son sinónimos y de uso habitual. “Flirtear”, anglicismo introducido en el siglo XIX y aceptado por la Real Academia Española, tiene un toque de modernidad. Una señorita del siglo XVIII podría coquetear, pero seguramente no flirtear.

“Ligar” tiene un significado un poco diferente: es algo más que flirtear, significa haber llegado a establecer algún tipo de relación amorosa o sexual, aunque sea superficial y pasajera. Si alguien ha ligado, no es solo que ha estado flirteando, sino que ha tenido éxito, hasta cierto punto al menos, con una persona concreta. Quien ha ligado, o ha entablado ya una relación sexual o tiene fundadas esperanzas de entablarlas pronto.

Lo que pasa es que hay gente que consume mucho tiempo *intentando* ligar y a lo mejor dice que “ha estado ligando”. Pero no, eso no es ligar. Y al que le pasa eso no es un ligón, sino seguramente un pelmazo.

Answer (score 6):

En España usamos mucho el verbo ***ligar***.

Este verbo es muy especial. Según yo lo entiendo, y habiendo vivido en Galicia, Madrid, y el País Vasco, en gerundio se refiere al acto de *intentar* establecer una relación ("está ligando con Pedro" = "está intentando establecer una relación con Pedro" o "está intentando llevarse a Pedro a la cama"), pero en pasado se refiere no al intento, sino al hecho de *haberlo conseguido* ("ligó con Pedro" = "estableció una relación con Pedro" o "se acostó con Pedro", no "intentó acostarse con Pedro"). Por eso, "ligó con Pedro" y "estuvo ligando con Pedro" son cosas *muy* distintas.

Answer (score 4):

En Argentina se usan mucho `levantar` y `chamullar`.

Ojo porque `chamullar` tiene varios otros matices, principalmente negativos.

Answer (score 3):

Como ya se ha dicho, en el norte de España usamos también meter fichas. De hecho, aquí en Galicia casi nadie usa ligar o coquetear, sino que casi todos hablamos de meter fichas o de mojar. Por ejemplo:

> -Va, tía, te está metiendo fichas.
>
> -Hoy el X moja.

Mojar normalmente viene de la expresión mojar la polla, usease, follar. Pero se usa tanto para chicos como para chicas.

Cuando tienes éxito, entonces te has liado con alguien (puede incluir desde besos hasta sexo).

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que aquí en Galicia, podemos tener comportamientos unos con otros en plan de colegas o de coña que mucha gente consideraría que no son propios si no estás ligando.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que hace difícil explicar regionalismos de la lengua Española es la expansión territorial del lenguaje a través del mundo.

Mi experiencia viajando a varios países alrededor del mundo y haber interactuado con personas de mucho países de habla hispana, lo mejor es tratar de aprender las palabras de uso común de la lengua Española. En este caso, la palabra "coquetear" es quizás la más común sinónimo de "flirtear".  Evitar malos entendidos es lo mejor que uno puede hacer.

Answer (score 2):

En Uruguay se dice `cargar`, o cargarse a alguien, también `ligar`, `levantar`, salir de ligue, de levante. No se usa para nada `flirtear`, que es la palabra que me ocupa en este momento. Se entiende y se usa también coquetear.

Comment: En España "cargarte" a alguien es "matar" a alguien o "romper" algo: "Quién se ha cargado mi coche teledirigido? Cuando le encuentre me lo voy a cargar!!". Si alguien "se la carga" es que recibe las consecuencias de algo: "has roto el jarrón y te la vas a cargar cuando llegue mamá".

Answer (score 2):

En **Chile** no hay una palabra para el coqueteo recíproco. Los mayores de 40 todavía decimos "pinchar", "ellos están pinchando", pero el uso está desprestigiado por anticuado.

Cuando una persona le coquetea a otra, la está "joteando" (los jotes son los buitres).

Comment: Una diferencia regional: si en España dijeses que "X está **pinchando a** Y" es como **incordiar** (no me pinches con el temita, por favor). Decir "X está **pinchando con** Y" por otro lado puede tener connotaciones sexuales, pero no creo que la mayoría de la gente usa este significado.