# Origen de la expresión "tirar los tejos"

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos

Una vez preguntado por el [origen de la palabra *chisme*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26336/12637), toca explicar sobre qué fue la conversación. Resulta que el chisme contaba que cierta persona del barrio solía *tirarle los tejos* a mi abuelo materno. Y claro, entonces pensé "qué bien, otra expresión curiosa para buscar su origen".

El DLE define la expresión como:

> **[tirar los tejos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZKqOe21#7czED1B)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Poner los puntos.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Insinuarle a alguien el interés que se tiene puesto en él, o manifestarle indirectamente lo que de él se espera.

Muy bien, pero ¿qué es un *tejo*? ¿Y por qué hay que tirarlo para intentar ligar con alguien?

> **[tejo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZKqOe21)**
>
> 1. m. Pedazo pequeño de teja o cosa semejante, que se utiliza en diversos juegos.
> 2. m. Cada uno de los juegos en que se emplea el tejo, como la rayuela o el chito.

Bien, parece que la cosa va de juegos, y efectivamente así [lo confirma Alfred López en su blog](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-tirar-los-tejos/):

> El origen de esta expresión proviene de un antiguo juego llamado el **tejo**, que consistía en tirar una piedra o trozo de teja [...] contra un palo de madera clavado/depositado en el suelo y cuyo objetivo era derribarlo. Normalmente se jugaba en plazas o parques públicos y en los que mientras unos jugaban otras personas paseaban o estaban sentadas en algún banco cercano.
>
> Era usual que, cuando a algún muchacho le gustaba una de las chicas que por allí se encontraban, tirase el tejo a una distancia cercana de donde estaba ésta y, con la excusa de ir a recogerlo, aprovechase para insinuarse, charlar o hacerle ver su interés por ella.

Muy bien, la explicación parece plausible, pero hay algo que no me cuadra. Hay referencias del juego del tejo en textos hasta del siglo XVI:

> *Ver a las mil maravillas
>
>   los juegos que allí s'armavan: [...]
>
>   Oras a hurta el capote,
>
>   oras a daca el ovillo,
>
>   oras asconde 'll orillo,
>
>   oras a dile más diote,
>
>   oras a hinca el picote
>
>   oras a passa morato,
>
>   y a la chueca y al garrote,
>
>   y al tejo y a guarda el hato.*
>
> Bartolomé de Torres Naharro, "Comedia Jacinta [Propaladia]", 1517 (España).

Y de hecho las acepciones mencionadas de *tejo* aparecen ya en el *Diccionario de Autoridades*. En cambio, solo encuentro casos de la expresión *tirar los tejos* en textos a partir de 1970 en el CORDE:

> *No, no era mala para novia la Media Almendra pero era poco para él y nunca le tiró los tejos del amor.*
>
> Antonio Díaz-Cañabate, "Paseíllo por el planeta de los toros", 1970 (España).

Me parece un salto muy grande como para que la expresión se haya popularizado de la forma en la que afirma Alfred López, dado que por lo que cuenta parecería que se haya usado así desde hace siglos. Sin embargo, la primera acepción coloquial de *tirar los tejos* se recoge en el DLE en 1956:

> **Tirar los tejos.** fr. fig. y fam. **Poner los puntos.**

El significado de esta última es:

> **[poner los puntos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UgMIq14#C8ewjsH)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. Dirigir la mira, intención o conato a un fin que se desea.

Es decir, parece que tiene su origen más en la acción de apuntar con la piedra o tejo a un objetivo, que a la picardía de tirar el tejo en la dirección "equivocada" con intenciones insinuatorias. De hecho, la acepción de insinuarse a una persona se recoge por primera vez en el *Academia Manual* de 1985. Tal vez por eso la expresión se usa en el ejemplo de 1970 como "tirar los tejos del amor", con esa necesidad de aclarar que son "del amor" y no de otra cosa.

Así pues, en principio la historia que cuenta Alfred es muy bonita pero no parece cierta. ¿O sí? ¿Se me escapa algo? ¿Hay algún uso de la expresión "tirar los tejos" o similar antes del siglo XX, que pueda hacer pensar que la historia es cierta? ¿O realmente la expresión se originó primero como sinónimo relativamente reciente de "poner el punto de mira en algo" de forma más genérica, y ya de ahí saltó al terreno amoroso? Me cuesta trabajo pensar que la expresión venga de antiguo y solo se transmitiera de forma oral hasta bien avanzado el siglo XX. ¿Tal vez he malinterpretado el artículo y el origen es el que afirma Alfred pero es mucho más reciente de lo que aparenta?

Comment: Sobre esa expresión (significado y origen) ya se ha tratado algo en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18504/what-does-tirar-los-tejos-mean

Answer (score 2):

El hecho de que haya referencias de que el juego date del siglo XVI (yo diría incluso que posiblemente antes) no quiere decir que originase la expresión en esa época.

La locución, evidentemente, es mucho más moderna (la situaría hacia finales del siglo XIX y principios del XX) pero es consecuencia directa de ese juego. Además siempre tardan muchas décadas en ser registradas las expresiones populares en los diccionarios (hasta que no son de uso muy común y popular). Podría darte docenas de ejemplos de palabras y frases que usamos habitualmente y que no aparecen recogidas en los diccionarios.

Comment: ¡Buenas, Alfred! Es un honor tenerte por aquí, hay muchos seguidores de tu blog presentes. Es cierto que hay muchas expresiones que tardan bastante tiempo en pasar de la expresión oral a la escrita. Indicas que la época de origen de la expresión es una suposición, pero aun así nos gustaría saber en qué te basas. Seguro que tienes muchas historias que contarnos (aunque poco tiempo, lo entiendo). Pásate cuando puedas y nos amplías la respuesta, estaremos ansiosos por aprender lo que nos tienes que contar (¡tanto en esta como en cualquier otra pregunta que encuentres interesante!).

Comment: Por cierto, hemos citado tu blog en varias ocasiones para escribir nuestras respuestas, así que si a cambio quieres coger inspiración de alguna de nuestras historias... ;-)

Comment: ¡Me uno a @Charlie dándote la bienvenida al sitio, Alfred! Yo también usé tu blog en distintas ocasiones para documentar respuestas de este sitio (se ha usado mucho, [mira la lista](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ya+est%C3%A1+el+listo+que+todo+lo+sabe%22) :) ) y quiero agradecerte la gran labor que vienes haciendo todos estos años. Ojalá te encuentres como en casa aquí en [spanish.se] y podamos ver muchas respuestas tuyas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por vuestra bienvenida. Debo reconocer que no conocía este foro de intercambio de información. Tiene una pinta estupendísima. Espero tener tiempo y echar un buen vistazo a vuestras entradas, seguro que habrá un gran número que me servirán para futuros posts en mi blog. Gracias también por las referencias y enlaces. En cuanto pueda (y regrese del viaje) retomo este hilo. Lamentablemente tengo unos horarios limitadísimos y lo que aparece en redes está programado con varios días (de vez en cuando asomo la nariz por si hay alguna mención). Un cordial saludo y hasta la próxima.